# How do I resolve the '@environment' bean in a Thymeleaf template in a Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring boot application that is headless (only presenting REST APIs), but I am using Thymeleaf for some email templates.

I have included

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in my dependencies.

When I include `@environment` in my template, I get the error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'environment'
```

My template code is, for example,

```
<p>
  <a th:href="${@environment.getProperty('system.clientUrl')} + '/verify?action=accept&verificationCode=' + ${verificationCode}">Verify</a>
</p>
```

where `system.clientUrl` is defined in the `application.properties` file.

Other aspects of Thymeleaf seem to work just fine (including when I defined the client URL in a resources bundle).

For other objects referenced in the template, I am passing a `Set<String,Object>` of template model objects.

```
Map<String, Object> templateModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    templateModel.put("verificationCode", emailVerification.getVerificationCode());
```

I suppose, I could pass the `Environment` or just the clientUrl in too, but I assumed that `@environment` is always available to the Thymeleaf renderer.

**Update**

My rendering code is

```
Context thymeleafContext = new Context();
thymeleafContext.setVariables(templateModel);
String htmlBody = thymeleafTemplateEngine.process(templateName, thymeleafContext);
```

Is there something I need to pass to the context?

Comment: Did you find solution to this? Appreciate if you could share your solution.